# How do I figure out what, if anything, a given command is doing in vim?

Tags: vim

I was thinking of mapping `,u` to uncomment a block of code in visual mode, but first I wanted to make sure that `,u` wasn't already doing something else important.

I selected three lines visually and typed `,u` and I got the message at the bottom of the screen (where : commands are entered): "3 lines changed".

The lines didn't change, but maybe they would have under some circumstances. Obviously, vim is claiming to have executed some command, but what?

I typed `:map` and `,u` was not listed as having been remapped. So I typed, :help `,u` and it told me "No help for `,u`" (read: No help for you!).

There's no `,u` or `<leader>u` in my .vimrc. I haven't redefined comma as my leader.

If it were the unix command line, I'd type `which ,u`, but I don't know any equivalent in vim.

How do I figure out what, if anything, a given command is doing in any particular running instance of vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual mode, the comma does  nothing but `u` lowercases the selected text.

This means that you can safely use `,u` for a visual mode mapping: you will still be able to use `u` but `,` followed immediately by `u` will do what you want.

The `:map` command only lists mappings. Since built-in operators are not mappings you won't be able to see them there.

When a "shortcut" doesn't appear in `:map`, try vim's awesome documentation:

```
:help v_u " shows help for u in visual mode (note the v_)
```

If you get nothing, either from `:map` or from `:help`, using the those keys for your mapping may not be completely trouble-free. A bit of trial and error may be necessary.

Suggested reading:

[Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/): Chapter [3](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/03.html), [4](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/04.html) and [5](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html).

Comment: It sounds as though you have to already mostly know how vim interprets a given command ("in visual mode, it ignores commas and therefore interprets ,u as if it were u") in order to ask vim how it interprets the command. I was afraid that might be the case but was wondering whether there was some command parser display or some such hidden feature that would take ",u" and tell me what you're telling me. Oh, well, your answer is very useful in other ways.

Comment: That "command parser" is your brain and it works best after you acquired some experience.

Comment: True, but a meta-answer: "How do I figure out x?" "By having learned to figure out x". I now suspect the best specific answer in this case is a process, like 1) remove certain chars, 2) look for all or part of remainder in :map, 3) each mode has a different ignored chars list; remove those chars, 4) each mode has a list of used commands of various lengths; find that list and look for the longest sequence.... I don't know if this procedure is documented or if such mode-specific lists exist outside the vim code that uses them. ALSO: Your answer has helped me, and I appreciate it.

Comment: Notable exceptions are `zsomething`, `gsomething` and `<C-something>` but most commands are one character long. When you encounter a multi-characters command that is a. not listed in `:map` and b. not part of the three categories above, assuming it's a compound command is the most obvious and safest road. In such a case, look for each character individually *for the specific mode that interests you*. `:viusage` has the full list of built-in commands available in each mode.

Comment: Wow, that :viusage is a treasure trove worth studying. I've never seen it mentioned in a learning vi(m) book that I recall. Thanks for pointing it out.